# Substitution after the end of the word

Tags: bash, sed

I have a huge text file with lots of lines like:

```
a 23232 23232 545 3434 DATA4545454_1 454 4646466 3434 3567
a 23232 23267632 545 3436764 DATA454545567564__1 454 464675466 3434 3
a 232676732 232676732 545 3434 DATA4545454_1 454 46457566466 3457534 35675
```

In all of them I would like to get rid of everything which is after DATA*, so I get:

```
a 23232 23232 545 3434 DATA4545454_1 
a 23232 23267632 545 3436764 DATA454545567564__1 
a 232676732 232676732 545 3434 DATA4545454_1
```

I know it can be done with sed and tried different combinations but I do not get the result, do you know how?

Thanks

Comment: If the answer on your last question wasn't what you wanted, you probably should've edited the question to ask what you really meant, rather than posting a new one.

Comment: hi jefromi, yes you are right. sorry but i am on a deadline and a bit confused now, i will take care later to learn from all your help. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(DATA[^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex which matches is

```
^(.+ DATA[0-9_]+).*$
```

which should be replaced with `$1`.

*Update*

That should be: replaced with `\1`.

Comment: Note: this is a perl answer, not a sed answer. (Sed can use extended regex, which would make it match, but it uses `\1`, not `$1`, for the captured group.)

Answer (score 0):

all your "DATA" appears at column 6. If its like that throughout, then simply

```
$ cut -d" " -f1-6 file
a 23232 23232 545 3434 DATA4545454_1
a 23232 23267632 545 3436764 DATA454545567564__1
a 232676732 232676732 545 3434 DATA4545454_1
```

or grep

```
$ grep -Eo ".*DATA.[^ ]* " file
a 23232 23232 545 3434 DATA4545454_1
a 23232 23267632 545 3436764 DATA454545567564__1
a 232676732 232676732 545 3434 DATA4545454_1
```

Comment: for some reason grep is not working with -o option.
`grep -Eo ".*DATA.[^ ]* " test_oq
grep: illegal option -- o`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(.*_1)(.*)/\1/'  file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(.* DATA.*_1\)\(.*\)/\1/'  file
```